# Difference between QScreen::width() and QScreen::deviceWidth(), QScreen::height() and QScreen::deviceHeight()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there difference between `QScreen::width()` and `QScreen::deviceWidth()` as both return width of the screen in pixels respectively?

Which are the appropriate usage scenarios of each of these functions?

Answer (score 1):

`QScreen::deviceWidth()` returns the physical width where as `QScreen::width()` returns the logical width. A note from the Qt documentation about physical/Logical DPI (DPI directly relates to width and height) :

> A note on logical vs physical dots per inch: physical DPI is based on
>   the actual physical pixel sizes when available, and is useful for
>   print preview and other cases where it's desirable to know the exact
>   physical dimensions of screen displayed contents.
>
> Logical dots per inch are used to convert font and user interface
>   elements from point sizes to pixel sizes, and might be different from
>   the physical dots per inch. The logical dots per inch are sometimes
>   user-settable in the desktop environment's settings panel, to let the
>   user globally control UI and font sizes in different applications.